# confirn in link on overlay lists

Tags: navigation, modal-dialogs

I create in administration list of some content and create link delete. On link delete I add attribute

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?);"
```

but when you click "cancel" on confirm block drupal still go to link href:

```
http://www.supermarket.hr/#overlay=admin/categories/delete/6939/0
```

How can I anticipate some hidden overlay functions that ignore added confirm?

thx

Comment: you want the confirm for delete or cancel ? drupal usually asks anyway again if you try to delete content.

Comment: I create table list with that link and add to it onclick option, but when you click on link on the overlay it still open href.

Comment: can you show some src pls

Answer (score 0):

Some code:

```
$option_delete = array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'onclick' => "return confirm('Delete order?');",
            'class' => "delete"
        )
    );
```

link:

```
l('delete', 'admin/orders/categories/'.$node->id.'/'.$page, $option_delete),
```

this link is showing up in list on administration overlay.

Comment: Found answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/36518/6520 interesting :)

Comment: so default was prevented ..